# Ugrading to jsf 2.2 from jsf 2.1

Tags: classnotfound, jsf-2.2

So I followed the setup instructions for upgrading to JSF 2.2 from http://www.mastertheboss.com/jsf/installing-jsf-22-on-jboss-as-7 using option 1. However, when I run JBOSS I am getting a class not found error, com/sun/faces/spi/InjectionProvider. Does anyone know where I can find this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be I'm late but for other peoples who fall into the same problem, I found a solution here : https://community.jboss.org/thread/203257?start=0&tstart=0

Add to the **module.xml** of your **JSF API module** a depency to the JSF IMPL module by adding this line :

```
<module name="com.sun.jsf-impl"/>
```

Some changes may be required when multiple JSF versions exists on the AS.
Tested with JBoss 7.1 and JSF 2.2.0m12